# Can't set up Ionic Push GCM because Firebase seems the only service available

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging

I can find no way to create a traditional GCM push account on Google Console. Everything routes to Firebase, and I cannot make any sense of these instructions http://docs.ionic.io/services/profiles/#android-gcm-project--api-key for how to set up Ionic Push for GCM now.

This must affect everyone using Ionic and GCM so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is encouraging new Cloud Messaging projects to use Firebase.

If you still decide to use the old steps in creating a GCM project (for you to follow the steps specified in the Ionic documentation, just head over to the Google Developer Console -> Create Project -> Create Server API Key. If asked to retrieve the configuration file, you'll need to [get the configuration file](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) here and set the appropriate data to download it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firebase Server Key as the GCM key, and the Firebase Send ID as the old Project Number parameter.